# str.replace(last_letter, second_letter) and replace(second_letter, last_letter) resulting in only one of them executing

Tags: python, string, str-replace, python-3.9, caesar-cipher

In the following Python code where I am deciphering a message that should theoretically result in *Ready, set go* output the two lines with str.replace() are obviously not executing as expected, resulting in only the second character of the word being replaced:

```
# Input:
# 82yade 115te 103o
#
# Output:
# Ready set go
user_input = input().split(" ")
first_letter = ''
second_letter = ''
last_letter = ''
printable_list = []
ord_char = ''
final_str = ''
concat_str = ''
for word in user_input:
    final_str = ''
    first_letter = ''
    last_letter = ''
    ord_char = ''
    concat_str = ''
    for idx in range(0, len(word)):
        if word[idx].isdigit():
            first_letter = word[idx]
            ord_char += first_letter
        else:
            final_str += word[idx]
    concat_str = chr(int(ord_char)) + final_str
    second_letter = concat_str[1]
    last_letter = concat_str[len(concat_str) - 1]
    print(second_letter, last_letter) # this prints here only for debugging purposes, e.g. to check 2nd and last letter
    concat_str = concat_str.replace(last_letter, second_letter)
    concat_str = concat_str.replace(second_letter, last_letter)
    printable_list.append(concat_str)
print(' '.join(printable_list))
```

Hence, what I expect to come out as *"Ready set go" is "Reade see go"*. What is causing the second replace to malfunction?

What I tried to achieve is that the second and the last letter are switched (e.g., Holle means Hello) and that the first letter is replaced by its character code (e.g., 72 means H) which runs smoothly until I hit the line replacing the 2nd with my last character of each of the words I add to the printable_list.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the string:

```
Ryade
```

If you replace the `last_letter` (`e`) with the `second_letter` (`y`) you get:

```
Ryady
```

Now if you replace `second_letter` (`y`) with `last_letter` (`e`) you get:

```
Reade
```

All of the y's were replaced with e's.

---

To get around this issue you can introduce a placeholder character (as one of many options):

```
placeholder = '^'    
concat_str = concat_str.replace(last_letter, placeholder)
concat_str = concat_str.replace(second_letter, last_letter)
concat_str = concat_str.replace(placeholder, second_letter)
```

With this logic our input of `Ryade` will take the following steps:

1. `Ryed^`
2. `Read^`
3. `Ready`

---

From my comment below, you may have better success being more tactical about which character you are replacing by using its position in the word (after swapping out that first letter). There are likely prettier ways to do this, but this feels like a reasonable direction:

```
import re 
user_input = input().split(" ")
printable_list = []
for word in user_input:    
    word = word.replace(re.findall('^[0-9]*', word)[0], chr(int(re.findall('^[0-9]*', word)[0])))    
    if len(word) > 2:
        word = word[0] + word[len(word) - 1] + word[2:len(word)-1] + word[1]
    printable_list.append(word)
print(' '.join(printable_list))
```

Comment: That works fine in the cases where I do not have repeating characters as in Ready set go, but as soon as I try deciphering a string that should result in Hello good day for example, I can't find a way to replace only the appropriate character, as the replace method replaces the first character with the particular ASCII or Unicode identifier it meets in the string, so I get Hello god^ day instead, when I set the count like this: concat_str.replace(second_letter, last_letter, 1) otherwise without count the output will be "Hello godd day".

Comment: Totally understandable. I think relying on `.replace()` here is the failure point where if you were more tactical about switching positions of characters in the word you less likely to run into edge cases like this. Will update with a proposed rewrite/solution.

Comment: I came to the conclusion too, though the hard way, this morning. :) So the solution for me was to use list[x], list[y] = list[z], list[j]. Thanks to everybody involved. Nevertheless, sadly, so far I still have no answer to the initial question why is the replace malfunctioning so badly... :(  The logical sequence in which I have ordered the two replacement methods should work, in theory, at least, right? What I ask with this is, is if you can tell me whether at least the sequencing of the actions I want to perform with the list correct?

Comment: "Should work in theory?" No. Please reread what I wrote about replace in the answer above. The sequence doesn't work without introducing the third step to add a placeholder. This is a common design paradigm with swapping data (here the swap being characters in words). If it helps, add a `print(concat_str)` between each `.replace()` so you can see and think through what is happening as those replaces take affect. You'll see it's impossible without a placeholder, or just being more tactical as we've both been with our rewrites.

Answer (score 1):

[`str.replace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) is based on `old` and `new` substrings, irrespective of positions.

> `str.replace(old, new[, count])`
>
> Return a copy of the string with all occurrences of substring *old* replaced by *new*. If the optional argument *count* is given, only the first *count* occurrences are replaced.

You can use [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#formatted-string-literals) to replace characters at specific positions:

```py
first_letter = concat_str[0]
second_letter = concat_str[1]
third_to_second_last_letter = concat_str[2:-1]
last_letter = concat_str[-1]
# concat_str = concat_str.replace(last_letter, second_letter)
# concat_str = concat_str.replace(second_letter, last_letter)
if len(concat_str) > 2:
    concat_str = f'{first_letter}{last_letter}{third_to_second_last_letter}{second_letter}'
```

A less performant but more obvious swap, using a `list` of characters since `str` is immutable:

```py
second_letter = concat_str[1]
last_letter = concat_str[-1]
# concat_str = concat_str.replace(last_letter, second_letter)
# concat_str = concat_str.replace(second_letter, last_letter)
concat_str_list = list(concat_str)
concat_str_list[1], concat_str_list[-1] = last_letter, second_letter
concat_str = ''.join(concat_str_list)
```